# Parsing JSON data from a URL in Haskell using Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I'm trying to create a web app in Haskell that takes some JSON input from a URL.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Aeson as Q
import Data.Text
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)
import GHC.Generics
--import Data.DateTime

data Temperatures = 
  Temperatures { date :: String
               , temperature :: Int
                 } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Temperatures
instance ToJSON Temperatures


jsonURL :: String
jsonURL = "http://www.phoric.eu/temperature"

getJSON :: IO B.ByteString
getJSON = simpleHttp jsonURL


main :: IO ()
main = do 
 d <- (eitherDecode <$> getJSON) :: IO (Either String Temperatures)
 case d of
  Left e   -> putStrLn e
  Right stuff -> print stuff
```

However, I'm getting the error at runtime:

```
Bradley$ runhaskell test.hs
The key "date" was not found
```

The JSON is below @ the URL which is in the code.

```
{"temperatures":[
    {"date":"2015-02-28T20:16:12+00:00", "temperature":0},
    {"date":"2015-01-01T21:46:55+00:00", "temperature":2}, 
    {"date":"2015-04-08T21:46:53+00:00", "temperature":3},
    {"date":"2015-04-09T21:46:01+00:00", "temperature":4},
    {"date":"2015-04-10T21:46:40+00:00", "temperature":5},
    {"date":"2015-04-11T21:46:36+00:00", "temperature":6},
    {"date":"2015-04-12T20:36:25+00:00", "temperature":7}
]}
```

I have no idea why it is not recognising the keys when they're clearly present in the JSON object, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current form, your code can only parse a single line of the form `{"date":"2015-04-12T20:36:25+00:00", "temperature":7}` : it tries to parse the input into a `Temperatures`, but can't find a `date` key into the root object because it only has a `temperatures` key.

The problem is that your `Temperatures` datatype does not really match your input. Here is something that should match:

```
data DataPoint = DataPoint { date :: String
                           , temperature :: Int
                           } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Temperatures = Temperatures { temperatures :: [DataPoint]
                                 } deriving (Show, Generic)
```